# Which of these is the correct way to calculate the volume of a tetrahedron?

Tags: calculus, integration, area

> Let $b$ a real positive number. Calculate the volume of the tetrahedrum delimited by the planes $x=0, y=0, z=0$ and $2bx+2y+z=2b$.

The first thing i've done is calculating the vertices of which are $(0,0,2b), (0,b,0), (1,0,0)$. Then, I want to see how the variables move.

First, we know $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Now, looking the $xy$ plane, we see that $0 \leq y \leq b-bx$.

The problem is with $z$, i found 2 ways to move it but the final integral ends up giving me different results. So, the first way is isolating $z$ from $2bx+2y+z=2b$, where we get $z = -2bx-2y+2b$. Then, the volume is

\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{1} \int\limits_{0}^{b-bx} \int\limits_{0}^{-2bx-2y+2b}1 \,dz\, dy\,dx = \frac{b^2}{3}
\end{equation}

On the other hand, if we look at the zy plane, we see that $z = 2b-2y$. In this case, we have

\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{1} \int\limits_{0}^{b-bx} \int\limits_{0}^{2b-2y}1 \,dz\,dy\,dx = \frac{2b^2}{3}
\end{equation}

What is the correct way to calculate it? Where is my mistake?

Comment: I would expect $\frac16 \cdot 2b \cdot b \cdot 1 = \frac13 b^2$.

Comment: If you "look at the zy" plane, then you need to describe $x$ in terms of $y, z$ and change the order of integration.

Comment: I would calculate the general area of a triangle defined by three points and then apply it to each set of three of the four points of the tetrahedron.

Comment: @DougM How's that? I think i don't understand what do you mean

Comment: If you wan't to "look at the yz" plane, and express $z$ in terms of $y$ you are projecting all values of $x$ onto the $yz$ plane, and must evaluate $x$ in the intergral first.

i.e. 

$\int_0^1\int_0^{b - bx}\int_0^{2b - 2bx - 2y} \ dz\ dy\ dx = \int_0^b\int_0^{2b - by}\int_0^{1 - \frac {y}{b} - \frac {z}{2b}} \ dx\ dz\ dy$

Comment: @DougM Oh, i get it now. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the comment by @DavidG.Stork refers to the title of the question, which is about the area, whereas the other comments refer to the body of the question, which is about the volume.

Comment: @jscherman:  Please fix the title of your question (area vs. volume).